# Tooltip submenu links giving weird URLs

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a site that uses jquery ajax to load all the pages. basically the its like `<a href="photos">photos</a>`. Then the jquery picks this up and goes to the correct folder and adds .php at end and loads that file into the content window. Then it puts that href attribute (in this case photos) and puts #current_pg_attr at end of url, so its like www.mysite.com/#photos if the content window is showing photos page. Also in one of my main menu, I have a submenu that shows only on hover and its like:

```
<ul id="main_nav"><br />
    <li><a href="home">home</a></li><br />
    <li><a href="photos">photos</a><br />
        <div id="menu2_submenu_tooltip"><a href="?com=viewall">view all stuff</a></div><br />
    </li><br />
</ul>
```

Now the problem arises when the submenu is clicked. Like if I click the view all stuff, it takes me to **www.mysite.com/#?com=viewall** instead of **www.mysite.com/?com=viewall#photos**. What am I doing wrong? I think it has to do with the line that adding jquery #somthing in url? This error url is not a problem as I can work around it by just getting GET variable, and loading that page, but still I want to try to get this right. By the way, here is the part of my ajax jquery code:

```
var curr_page_hash = window.location.hash;
    $('#main_center').load('content/' + curr_page_hash.substr(1) + '.php');
    window.location.hash = curr_page_hash;
    $('#left_nav ul li a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#main_center').html('<div id="load_img"><img src="template/img/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
    $('#main_center').load('content/' + page + '.php');
    window.location.hash = '#' + page; 
            return false;     
    });
```

Any help on issue?

Comment: In your click handler, it grabs the href and puts a # in front of it and set it to the hash. So the result you get is correct. If you want the photo to be included, you need to grab that hash first, append it in the correct order. Maybe something like window.location.hash = page + "#" + originalHash;

Comment: can you provide me an example of how to do this? I kind of get a general idea, but will help if i saw an example.

Answer (score 0):

To heck for original hash you can do something like

```
// note I am not sure what window.location.hash returns if there is no hash but you should test that first to make this more efficient
var t = window.location;
var originalHash = "";
if(t.indexOf("#") > -1) {
   // grab the hash
   originalHash = window.location.hash;
}
```

so that takes care of the original hash, now to set the new page you can leave your code the way it is and do this at the end

```
// don't need to add # because it is in originalHash already, it is safe to add originalHash because if there is no # in URL then it will be empty string
window.location.hash = page + originalHash;
```

If you tried this and it does not work, make sure you edit the question and post your newest code

Comment: Another problem I realized with the above code is with my jquery style ajax page loads. The submenus that I have like the one that links to a GET variable. When I click it, the jquery redirects the page to the name of the GET variable + .php. Since this page doesn't exist, nothing is loaded. Now the problem is I want to stay on the main menu photos page and the subpage just adds GET variable in the url and thus the main photos page changes along with what the get variable is. Thus having code like this on photos page:      'if ($_GET['com'] == 'viewall') { //do something }'

Comment: you should post another question as I am not too familiar with PHP